# Symfony 6 - How to prevent login success when 2fa is activated?

Tags: authentication, symfony, security, two-factor-authentication, php-8.1

When I sign in the 2fa form is shown and login is successful befor enter the authenticate code sent by mail.
I'm using php8.1 and Symfony6.3

```
#** scheb_2fa.yaml**

scheb_two_factor:
    security_tokens:
        - Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Token\PostAuthenticationToken
    email:
        digits: 6
        enabled: true
        sender_email: no-reply@myDomain.com
        sender_name: My App
        template: security/2fa_form.html.twig
```

```
   #**security.yaml**
   
   firewalls:
       main:
           two_factor:
                auth_form_path: 2fa_login 
                check_path: 2fa_login_check

   access_control:
        - { path: ^/logout, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/2fa, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_2FA_IN_PROGRESS }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The user must be authenticated only after inserting the auth code.

Thanks for your help.